# Type 'Any' has no subscript members in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

I apologize for the title. I understand this is a common issue in Swift. I read the answers in other threads and I believe I'm a little closer to solving the problem.

I have an array of dictionaries `var userObjects: [[String:AnyObject]] = []`

I'm using it to populate a collectionview. In my cellForItemAt function, I have

```
guard let user = userObjects[indexPath.row]["data"] as? [String:AnyObject] else { return cell }
guard let firstName = user["first_name"] else {return cell}
```

I was getting the typical `Type 'Any' has no subscript members` error in the second line in the snippet above until I added `as? [String:AnyObject]` to the first line in the snippet. The problem is now the code breaks at the first guard statement for `user` as if the statement is not true.

What am I doing wrong, and how do I properly cast the objects?

Example of what an element in `userObjects` looks like:

```
{
    count = 1;
    data =     (
                {
            email = "tester2@test.com";
            "first_name" = Tester;
            gender = Male;
            instagram = "n/a";                      
            "last_name" = One;
            preference = Female;
            profileImageURL = "n/a";
        }
    );
    page = 0;
    pageCount = 1;
    perPage = 20;
```

Comment: Before subscript, cast value of Any to appropriate type (e.g. Dictionary<String, Any>)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say

```
guard let user = userObjects[indexPath.row]["data"] as? [String:AnyObject] else { return cell }
```

...you are saying that `user` is the `"data"` entry:

```
data = (
            {
                email = "tester2@test.com";
                "first_name" = Tester;
                gender = Male;
                instagram = "n/a";                      
                "last_name" = One;
                preference = Female;
                profileImageURL = "n/a";
    }
);
```

That's not a dictionary. It's an *array* of dictionaries. Hence, the attempt to subscript it with `"first_name"` fails.

Comment: You are right! Thank you for pointing that out to me. So if I define my objects as `userObjects[indexPath.row]["data"] as? [[String:AnyObject]]`, how can I subscript a value of type `[[String:AnyObject]]`?

Comment: Well which one do you want? If the first one, it's `[0]`. It's an array.

Comment: That was it! Thank you matt! Final solution was `guard let user = userObjects[indexPath.row]["data"] as? [[String:AnyObject]] else { return cell }` and then getting a value with `guard let firstName = user[0]["first_name"] else {return cell}`

Comment: That's great, but having said all that, what you're doing seems un-Swift-like. Where's this data coming from? That is, where did you get `userObjects` to start with? It seems to me that you should parsing it into Swift objects, so that you have no need for untyped things like Any or AnyObject.

Comment: I'm getting the data from algolia and firebase. I store the user information in firebase, run search queries using algolia, and then return the search results in the client. It's definitely not ideal but it's necessary until Firebase Firestore supports geoqueries

Comment: OK, but if it's coming in as, say, JSON, and if it has a regular format, you can probably do this in a cleaner way quite easily. I understand that that might not be possible...

Answer (score 1):

According to your user data, data is an array of key-value pairs so first You have to get data from the dictionary then you need to get the object from data(array of the dictionary) like this:

You can subscript a value of type [[String: AnyObject]] :-

```
guard let user = userObjects["data"][indexPath.row] as? [String:AnyObject] else { return cell }
guard let firstName = user["first_name"] else {return cell}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to cast `userObjects[indexPath.row]` to `Dictionary`

```
let userData = userObjects[indexPath.row] as? [String:Any]

guard let user = userData?["data"] as? [String:Any] else { return cell }

guard let firstName = user["first_name"] else {return cell}
```